# How can I transfer numbers that I input on my STM32 controller into a variable in CubeIDE?

Tags: stm32

The operating system that I am using is windows. The programs that I am using are CubeIDE and TouchGFX. The full name of the microcontroller is STM32H750B-DK.

I have implemented some code for my releys to do certain combinations of opening and closing. I have also programmed a keyboard on which I can input numbers and this numbers appear on the screen. The thing that I am trying to do is to write numbers on the STM32 controller and make them store into a variable in the code so this specific inputs can be used once I launch the part of the code where releys gain and lose contact.

I am not looking for a specific answer, I would just like to know where to start.

Comment: That's a very broad question - it's not clear which part you are having trouble with. But a good place to start would be the [TouchGFX documentation](https://support.touchgfx.com/docs/development/ui-development/ui-components/buttons/button-with-icon).

Comment: I dont really know how to ask more specificly since I am new at this. I'll start there than, thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a very ambitious project for a beginner. Most people start with blinking an LED or writing something on a UART, not a GUI-based project controlling relays.

Comment: I have already done the blinking LEDs thing. The custom made relay modules work the same way as LEDs (with GPIO pins) so that wasnt a big problem to implement. Ill take a look at UART I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It works as a buffer since nobody was able to tell me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).